# How to put less than operater on css3 selector?

Tags: css

If I have a tag like this

```
<div id='testdiv' style='height:300px;'></div>
```

How can I write a css rule that says

> select tag with id `testdiv` where it contains a style attribute that has height property whose value is less than 400px

Is this possible?

Comment: Not currently possible. You would have to do this with JavaScript for the time being. Element queries are a somewhat controversial topic right now.

Comment: if you`sass` or `less` then you can use `variables` http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in the current standard of CSS. `CSS4` might include a selector for it, but that's for far in the future. However it is possible using JavaScript or jQuery.

It must be noted that IDs must be unique. You should use classes if you want to use the same name.

In jQuery, the `filter` function should be able to solve this.

```
var smallDivs = $(".test-div").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("height") < 400;
});
```

It might also be possible in SASS, where you can create functions.